# HTML span tag gets an id="transmark" on double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why some of my HTML items get an additional `<span id="transmark"> </span>` when I double click on them?

```
<p class="messageError">
Bitte geben Sie ein n
eues Kenn
w
<span id="transmark"></span>
ort ein.
</p>
```

and when is not focused I see this:

```
<p class="messageError">Bitte geben Sie ein neues Kennwort ein.</p>
```

Extra info: The `<p>` tag can be clicked on and fades out (Jquery used)

What I do extra in Jquery:

```
     var textMessage="<?php echo $errorText;?>";
     $('#divid:first-child').prepend("<p class='messageError'>"+textMessage+"</p>");
```

and this:

```
    $('div#divid > p').on('click',function(){
       console.log($(this));
       $(this).slideUp('fast');
    });
```

LE: As a fix I set this in CSS

`#transmark{ //firefox bug fix
    display: none;
}`

Comment: you should show us your js too

Comment: have any malware or malicious plugins? If your code doesnt do anything remotely related to that, this might be it

Comment: probably in your js there is a event triggered which works on double click to add class to span

Comment: @MeeneshJain no is not.. I searched the whole project for the id="transmark"

Comment: did you search the string `#transmark`

Comment: @MeeneshJain yes all simple related combinations

Comment: @Edwin which browser are you using? You might want to check what plugins and extensions are actively running.

Comment: Google site map genarator are you using anywhere ?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly the question is asked by edwin

Comment: @n01ze no I'm not using and the same error I have on a browser without any installed plugins, just the default instalation.

Comment: 'transmark' things is used my google site map generator it seems, **NOT sure

Answer (score 0):

We saw this markup being inserted into contenteditable divs.

```
<span style=\"display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px;\" id=\"transmark\"></span>
```

Disabling this firefox plugin stopped it for us.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-selection-translate-for/?src=userprofile

Comment: I don't have that plugin installed, but I think is just a Firefox thing, because in chrome I don't have this problem.